# how to get Data from server and place the data into spinners

Tags: android

I got response from server and I want to set the values for first, second and third spinner. I can set values for first spinner only.but i didn't get solution for displaying values for remaining two spinners. It appears as black/empty. I don't know where the problem.  can anyone find solution for this one and let me know.

Here is my code.

```
public class Send extends Fragment {

    Spinner sp1, sp2, sp3;
    Button b1, b2;
    Bitmap bmp;
    String image;

    ImageView iview;
    Intent i = new Intent();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.send, container, false);
        sp1 = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.categories);
        sp2 = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.selectCity);
        sp3 = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.selectArea);
        b1 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.search);

        b2 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.clear);
        new DownloadJSON().execute();
        /* new MyTask().execute(); */
        return v;
    }




    // Download JSON file AsyncTask
    private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        JSONObject jsonobject;
        JSONArray jsonarray;
        ArrayList<String> worldlist;
        ArrayList<WorldPopulation> world;

        ArrayList<String> listnew;
        ArrayList<String> sp;

        ProgressDialog pDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();

            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            pDialog.setMessage("Fetching food categories..");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Locate the WorldPopulation Class
            world = new ArrayList<WorldPopulation>();
            // Create an array to populate the spinner
            worldlist = new ArrayList<String>();
            listnew = new ArrayList<String>();
            sp = new ArrayList<String>();
            // JSON file URL address
            jsonobject = JSONfunctions
                    .getJSONfromURL("http://creersoft.com/webservices/ajaxData.php?category_id=1&city_id=Lagos");

            try {
                JSONObject maJsonObject = jsonobject.getJSONObject("Response");
                JSONArray jsonArray = maJsonObject.getJSONArray("Result");
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    jsonobject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    WorldPopulation worldpop = new WorldPopulation();

                    worldpop.setId(jsonobject.optInt("id"));
                    worldpop.setName(jsonobject.optString("name"));
                    worldpop.setName(jsonobject.optString("city"));
                    worldpop.setArea(jsonobject.optString("area"));

                    world.add(worldpop);

                    // Populate spinner with country names
                    worldlist.add(jsonobject.optString("name"));
                    listnew.add(jsonobject.optString("city"));
                    sp.add(jsonobject.optString("area"));

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
            // Locate the spinner in activity_main.xml
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();

            // Spinner adapter
            sp1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, worldlist));
            sp2.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, listnew));
            sp3.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, sp));

            // Spinner on item click listener
            sp1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int position, long arg3) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }
            });
            sp2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }
               });
               }
               }
             }
```

Here is my JSON Response :

> {"Response":{"Success":"1","Result":[{"id":"1","name":"Groceries &
>   Convenience"},{"id":"2","name":"Pharmacy "},{"id":"3","name":"Fashion
>   &
>   Accessories"},{"id":"4","name":"Electronics"},{"id":"5","name":"Beauty
>   & Wellness"},{"id":"6","name":"Food"},{"id":"7","name":"Books &
>   Games"},{"id":"8","name":"For Kids"},{"id":"9","name":"Home &
>   Living"},{"id":"10","name":"Travel & Hotels"}]}}
>
> {"Response":{"Success":"1","Result":[{"city":"Abuja"},{"city":"Enugu"},{"city":"Kano"},{"city":"Lagos"}]}}
>
> {"Response":{"Success":"1","Result":[{"area":"Lekki"}]}}

Comment: Could you explain in more detail what your problem would be? What do you mean with "Here i will paste my code in my i got response from server"?

Comment: SaschaM78 I got response from server.i took 3 spinners.I set dta to three spinners.for first spinner only i got data.i didn't get data to remaining two spinners.it looks like empty

Comment: @SarathNadela  put debug here: listnew.add(jsonobject.optString("city"));
                sp.add(jsonobject.optString("area")); and check you get data here

Comment: Damini Mehra yes i think i got error here.listnew.add(jsonobje‌​ct.optString("city"))‌​; sp.add(jsonobject.op‌​tString("area"));But in logcat i didn't find any error regarding about this.

Comment: @SarathNadendla plz check your json data on: http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/ i think it is not properly formatted

Comment: i got json response as Spinner1 :{"Response":{"Success":"1","Result":[{"id":"1","name":"Groceries & Convenience"},{"id":"2","name":"Pharmacy "},{"id":"3","name":"Fashion & Accessories"},{"id":"4","name":"Electronics"},{"id":"5","name":"Beauty & Wellness"},{"id":"6","name":"Food"},{"id":"7","name":"Books & Games"},{"id":"8","name":"For Kids"},{"id":"9","name":"Home & Living"},{"id":"10","name":"Travel & Hotels"}]}}

Comment: SPinner2:-{"Response":{"Success":"1","Result":[{"city":"Abuja"},{"city":"Enugu"},{"city":"Kano"},{"city":"Lagos"}]}}                                Spinner3:-{"Response":{"Success":"1","Result":[{"area":"Lekki"}]}}

Comment: No Damini Mehra My JSON is good but separately we have to check for 3 spinners .i have 3 responses in my JSON for first,second and third

Answer (score 1):

I think `JSONArray jsonArray = maJsonObject.getJSONArray("Result");` is getting only

```
"Result":[{"id":"1","name":"Groceries & Convenience"},{"id":"2","name":"Pharmacy "},{"id":"3","name":"Fashion & Accessories"},{"id":"4","name":"Electronics"},{"id":"5","name":"Beauty & Wellness"},{"id":"6","name":"Food"},{"id":"7","name":"Books & Games"},{"id":"8","name":"For Kids"},{"id":"9","name":"Home & Living"},{"id":"10","name":"Travel & Hotels"}]
```

and this does not have `city` property. You should iterate separately other `Response` json objects too to get other results contains `city` and `area` properties.

Comment: faranjit if you have code for this type of example  can you please paste here

Comment: Your format of json result is wrong. You try to have 3 different `Response` json object but it is not true. You should return from api a json array which has 3 elements named `Response` and than loop in this array get `Response` objects like this `JSONObject maJsonObject = parentJsonArray.getJSONObject(0);`. The first `Response` object is for first spinner, second object is for second spinner and third object is for third spinner.

Comment: my requirement is if  i select categories i have to get categories related cities in next spinner and then if i select a city then i have to get the city related areas i would like to write code for this one can any one suggested me the code server side code and Android code